# Vagrant Binary unable to resolve dependency 'delegate'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vagrant, hashicorp

I was trying to use vagrant today and ran into a weird error with its dependencies. Any `vagrant` binary command I run just fails with the following error message.

> /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1453:in rescue in block
> in activate_dependencies': Could not find 'delegate' (>= 0) among 99
> total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError) Checked in
> 'GEM_PATH=/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.0' at:
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/specifications/weakref-0.1.1.gemspec, execute
> 'gem env' for more information

I've tried the following things:

- Reinstalling vagrant
- Removing vagrant and installing ruby separately
- Trying to install the `delegate` package with Gem Messing with the
- GEM_PATH env variable

I'm currently using vagrant version 2.3.0 on 64 bit arch linux.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because from the vagrant tag: GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 1):

If you using Arch, downgrading ruby to v3.0.4-5 should help, it works for me.

There is an issue on vagrant github: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/12843